# google script add link in UI text

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google script designed to create a PDF. I have it set on completion to provide a pop up showing the location of the file.

```
> ui.alert('Quote made check folder https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/......')
```

However this is just text and not a clickable link, could someone please guide me on how to make this a clickable link.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

this could work for you:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
var htmlApp = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput('Quote made check folder <a href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/......">LINK</a>')
     .setTitle('My HtmlService Application')
     .setWidth(250)
     .setHeight(80);

 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(htmlApp);

}
```